# In Python, how can I use Selenium to remove overlays from a webpage before printing to PDF?

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver, pdf

I am working on a Python script that prints a webpage to PDF. However, if a webpage has a popup such as "Sign up for our Newsletter" or "Accept All Cookies" etc. then that gets printed on top of the article or whatever I am trying to print.

Is there a way to **automatically** identify these elements and remove them / close them before printing to PDF using Python?

I have seen methods where you go identify the CSS object and then exclude it etc. but I need an automated method that doesn't take manual input for differing websites.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can do this fully automated. Every website is different, it would be difficult to tell which html elements are necessary and which aren't. You could set up some rules for what to remove, (eg. if a div contains the word "cookies" then remove it.) but this wouldn't work amazingly

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: @mrblue6 do you have any example of how I could try that?

Comment: @ColtonCampbell I'm not sure exactly how to do it tbh. CSS has something where you can specify styles for when a document is printed. With that you could simply do: 
```css
@media print {

    #example-div {
        display: none;
    }
}
```
This CSS code will not display the element with id: example-div when the document is printed.
Sorry, but not sure how to do this in python.